# 2nd invaild response is getting accepted in my validation loop

Tags: c++, stdin

The problem I am getting now is that I can input random things the 1st time and it works right but on the 2nd try it will take wrong inputs. EX: 1st input chess, it will say try again. 2nd input chess it will accept chess and open checking then put the h into deposit amount causing an error try again

```
case 1:
    cout << "Checking (C) or Savings (S): enter your choice" << endl;
    cin.get(choice);

    //input validation
    while(choice != 'c' && choice != 'C' && choice != 's' && choice != 'S')
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
        cin.get(choice);
    }

    //deposit in checking
    if (choice == 'c' || choice == 'C')
    {
        cout << "how much are you depositing: $" << endl; //get deposit
        cin >> deposit;

        while(!(cin >> deposit)) //make sure user input is valid
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
        }
```

Comment: this is a homework assignment but this part is not required I'm just trying to learn a little more about input validation loops because they are going to be in our next project.

Comment: Your code is missing a closing brace (`}`) at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will accept any input that starts with a `c` or a `s` (or their uppercase counterparts).

`cin.get(choice)` will read the first character from the stream and store it in `choice`, which you later use as the conditional in the loop.

A better approach would be to read an entire line from the stream and check that it equals  any of the correct choices.

```
std::cout << "Checking (c) or Savings (s) enter your choice: ";
std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::transform(std::begin(line), std::end(line), std::begin(line),
        ::tolower); // Transform line to lower case.
    if (line == "c" || line == "s") {
        break;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Invalid input. Try again: ";
    }
}
```

Comment: but why does it not accept it the 1st time then accept it the second time?

Comment: and I don't understand std:: stuff yet so your example is a little confusing

Comment: @user2087867 Your code accepted the input string `chess` both the first and subsequent times when I compiled and ran it.

Comment: @user2087867 All classes and functions in the standard library is defined in the `std` namespace. You can either use `using namespace std` at the top of your code or (preferably) use a `std::` in front of every declaration that refers to the standard library.

Comment: very strange. I am using visual studio 2010. I wonder why they act different

Comment: See [this example](http://ideone.com/7PwYWN) of how it always gets accepted (see `stdin` and `stdout` at bottom).